# Write with innerHTML on a selectable table by user

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to write with innerHTML on a 3 td selectable by user and write the text who write in text area.

```
    function texFil (){

selFi = new Array('td1', 'td2', 'td3');

selFi[0] = document.getElementById('te').value;
selFi[1] = document.getElementById('te').value;
selFi[2] = document.getElementById('te').value;

var i = document.getElementById('fi').value;

document.getElementById("selFi[i]").innerHTML; //this show in the td the text written in textarea by user.

}
```

**this is my script now and this my HTML:**

```
<table align="center" id="ta">
<tr><td id="td1">1.</td></tr>
<tr><td id="td2">2.</td></tr>
<tr><td id="td3">3.</td></tr>
</table><br>
<form id="fo" align="center">
Introduce text:<br><br>
<textarea type="text" id="te" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>
Indicate row:<br><br>
<input type="text" id="fi"><br><br>
<input type="button" id="ini" value="Start" onclick="texFil();">
```

**What i'm doing wrong??**

Comment: What you are trying to do first tell me?

Comment: Any error? How does your script behave?

Comment: enter text into text area, select the row, press button, the text is written to the specified row innerHTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT

```js
var cells = ['td1','td2','td3'];

function texFil() {
  
  var indicated = document.getElementById('fi').value;
  
  var index = parseInt(indicated);
  if(index > 0)
  {
     document.getElementById(cells[index -1]).innerHTML = document.getElementById('te').value;
    
  }
}
```

```html
<table align="center" id="ta">
  <tr>
    <td id="td1" >1.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="td2" >2.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="td3" >3.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<form id="fo" align="center">
  Introduce text:
  <br>
  <br>
  <textarea type="text" id="te" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
  <br>
  <br>Indicate row:
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="fi">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="ini" value="Start" onclick="texFil();">
```

Comment: please click on 'Run code snippet' of my answer, then tell me what in the behaviour don't fit with your requirenment

Comment: Your code doesn't run. I want to enter text into text area, select the row, press button, the text is written to the specified row in html doc. Thanks.

Comment: Ye i see in the screen but in my computer doesn't... :S

Comment: just a sec I will add some style to markup to make more clear what is the clickable areas

Comment: click the gray cell to select it, the cell will be bordered in red, write in the area then click the button, eh have a nice day :)

Comment: How you indicate the row?

Comment: try now, insert 1,2 or 3 in the input, write the content in the textarea, click button

Comment: Ye! Right work's well. I pose wrong scripting... Really thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```html
function texFil() {

                selFi = new Array('td1', 'td2', 'td3');
                var s = selFi[0] + selFi[1] + selFi[2];
                document.getElementById('te').value = s;


                var i = document.getElementById('fi').value;

                document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML;

            }
```

Comment: see the selFi[i] write.